why ANSI codes for colors not working in my NetBeans?
i wrote those codes and when i run them the color not appear in my console and my jdk is 20 and my NetBeans is 21 and i don't know why it isn't working really i need it to work.
package com.mycompany.shaz;

public class Shaz {

    final static String red="\u001b[31m";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(red+"Hello World!");
        String greenBold = "\033[32;1m";
        String reset = "\033[0m";

        System.out.println("before" + greenBold + " green " + reset + "after");

    }

}

i tried to fix it but i didn't find any tutorial to fix it because i don't know what is the problem

maybe Netbeans console does not support ANSI codes - first link when searching points back to StackOverflow: Colored output in netbeans console with ansicodes (I do not use Netbeans, so I cannot test it - works on VIM, DOS command line, and Eclipse - code is OK)

what you suggest i do to fix it?

maybe some settings... but isn't it strange, the second part of your code seems exactly the same as of one answer of that question I posted the link to ??? (OK, one added empty line)

i don't know what to do with the setting

Seems to be dependent on the used build system: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/5552
